# xslt with xpath that get some information from xml file doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

I've got an xml file. It is meant for being transformed by xslt processor. The specific template is ready, however it use some information from two additional xml files. All information is used to produce the proper output.

It works fine when I open the main xml file with my browser. The problem is: the result is just a fragment of website, it is an HTML element ready for being appended as a child. That is why I want to transform the xml with the xslt processor within a JavaScript function. Unfortunatelly, the result is half-way done. All what don't need the additional information from these two xml files imported by xpath expression is transformed well. The rest is shortly speaking absent.

JavaScript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor()
xhttp.open("GET", "contentTemplate.xsl", false)
xhttp.send()
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xhttp.responseXML)

function buildElement(what) {
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "root", null)
xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement(what))

var resultDocumentFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document)
return resultDocumentFragment
}
```

xslt:

there is lots of stuff, I paste just the xslt with xpath expression

```
<xsl:variable name="extInfo" select="document('tagAvailableToAdd.xml')/root"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$extInfo/tag">
 <option>
  <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="tagName"/></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
 </option>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and that is just absent. Just like no information was delivered.

EDIT:

it works in firefox, doesn't in chrome. I need to improve it. Actually, I don't know how.

Comment: What does `xhttp.responseXML` hold?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a list of possible reasons for this problem.

Comment: xhttp.responseXML holds stylesheet obtained from server. The stylesheet knows how to transform xml files that represent pages available to view in the browser. I use it to build the HTML node I can put into website. (BTW it gives me power to define my own tags e.g. <windowElement/>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had solved the problem, however an issue in firefox has occured.

Nevertheless, I concern chrome my native browser, that is why i'm glad I made it work in this program. That is the change I implemented in JavaScript:

```
function talkToServer(address, synch, func) {
func = typeof(func) != 'undefined' ? func : null
xhttp.open(method, address, synch)
xhttp.onreadystatechange = func
xhttp.send()
}

function getXPath(query) {
return document.evaluate(query, xhttp.responseXML, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
}

function buildElement(what) {
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "root", null)
xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement(what))

switch(what) {
case "windowElement":
talkToServer("tagAvailableToAdd.xml", false)
var additionalInfo = getXPath("/root/tag")
var aim = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("windowElement")[0]
for(i=0;i<additionalInfo.snapshotLength;i++)
    aim.appendChild(additionalInfo.snapshotItem(i).cloneNode(true))

talkToServer("cssTemplates.xml", false)
additionalInfo = getXPath("/root/*")
aim.appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement("css"));
aim = aim.getElementsByTagName("css")[0]
for(i=0;i<additionalInfo.snapshotLength;i++)
    aim.appendChild(additionalInfo.snapshotItem(i).cloneNode(true))
break;
}
var resultDocumentFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document)
return resultDocumentFragment
}
```

in xslt now I have all information in , so there is no need to import any external info.

main function is buildElement. I'm sure everybody can see what it does. It'a aim is to provide sth I can "paste" to HTML document.

In chrome it works. In firefox says: Node cannot be used in a document other than the one in which it was created" code: "4, and points at return statement in getXPath function. I don't know how ti fix it, but who cares, it is just firefox (I know it's stupid). In IE it suck, because xhttp is XHttpRequest object, but I believe, that when I provide ActiveX it should give what I want.

If you feel you can help me with the firefix issue, write a comment.

Comment: ok, I have already found solution. The return statement is now: return xhttp.responseXML.evaluate(query, xhttp.responseXML, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)

Comment: Wouldn't be more easy (and crossbrowser) just to pass the external document as a parameter to the trasformation?

Comment: What you mean? I think it is just what I'm doing. I pass xml file as a parameter to transformation here: xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document). If there was way to pass more xml files to transformation procedure, I'd definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

> xslt:
>
> there is lots of stuff, I paste just
>   the xslt with xpath expression
>
> ```
> <xsl:variable name="extInfo" select="document('tagAvailableToAdd.xml')/root"/>
>
> <xsl:for-each select="$extInfo/tag"> 
>  <option> 
>   <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of
> ```
>
> select="tagName"/>
>
> and that is just absent. Just like no
>   information was delivered.

**Some possible reasons for this behaviour**:

1. The URI of the XML file is not the right one. This is a relative URI and this specific URI will mace the XSLT processor look for a file named `'tagAvailableToAdd.xml'` and residing at the base-uri of the stylesheet. However, in this case the stylesheet is obtained dynamically and this means it doesn't have any base-uri. This is the most possible reason for the problem.
2. The Javascript doesn't have permissions to access files in the local file system.
3. The `document()` function isn't allowed by default by the XSLT processor.
4. The text contained in the file is not a well-formed XML document.
5. The top element of the XML file is not named `root`.

**Solution**: Specify an absolute URI as the argument to the `document()` function.

Comment: "The top element of the XML file is not named root" - i've checked it: there is root element; that's ok. "The text contained in the file is not a well-formed XML document" - why it works when i enter it directly? i think it's not the point. "The document() function isn't allowed by default by the XSLT processor" - how can I check it? now it isn't obvious. "The Javascript doesn't have permissions to access files in the local file system" - no error arouses - don't know if it occures. "The URI of the XML file is not the right one" the URI is relative to position of xsl file on server.

Comment: @lord.didger: probably you should use `try/catch` or analyze return codes. As for enabling the `document()` function, you need to read the documentation of the XSLT processor that is used by your browser.

Comment: i used try/catch to analyze "var resultDocumentFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document)" - it uses the stylesheet and in my opinion fails. No error catched, it returs what I see. MY GOD - it works in firefox - i tested it in chrome previously. Now i have to change the question :/

Comment: @lord.didger: So, what is the browser you are using?

Comment: @lord.didger: The reason No. 1 is the true reason for your problem. I edited my answer, providing more information and also a solution.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: i tried to change the relative adres to absolute. Result: document('http://localhost/cssTemplates.xml'), but it doesn't work on my local server.

Comment: @lord.didger: Can you display 'http://localhost/cssTemplates.xml' in your browser? If not, then this is not the right URL. Also, do you have at all an installed and working web server on your local box?

Comment: Chrome has a very strict politic about same domain... No `file:` protocol, as example. But, if there is an error the error console will inform it.

Comment: I have on my local box fully operation apache server with php and php-xsl. @Dimitre Novatchev: I can enter the URL you specified. I test the page also on external server where it is supposed to be in the future. You can see it youself: modent.home.pl/smile/#createPage. Press "+". The box which appears should be like that one that you can see here: modent.home.pl/smile/test.xml.

Comment: @lord.didger: Have you tried to replace `document('tagAvailableToAdd.xml')` with `document('http://modent.home.pl/smile/'tagAvailableToAdd.xml')`

Comment: I did on both local and external server. Unless I find solution that fixes the problem in chrome, I'll change the idea (i'm not glad about it) and answer my own question.